RevenueCat configuration error with Flutter
I initialize my code as below but I get this error :

There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details. There's a problem with your configuration. None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from App Store Connect (or the StoreKit Configuration file if one is being used).

Code:
Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());

  await _configureSdk();
}

Future<void> _configureSdk() async {
  await Purchases.setLogLevel(LogLevel.debug);

  PurchasesConfiguration? configuration;

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    //
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    configuration = PurchasesConfiguration('apikey');
  }

  if (configuration != null) {
    await Purchases.configure(configuration);
    print('configure');
 await RevenueCatUI.presentPaywallIfNeeded('Premium');
  }
}

await RevenueCatUI.presentPaywallIfNeeded('Premium');

ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  await RevenueCatUI.presentPaywallIfNeeded('Premium');
                },
                child: Text('purchases'))

I tried to open the paywall page in this way after clicking the button but I got the same error.

I think your configuration code needs to be called in your app state using the initState method instead of in main, something like this:
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureSdk();
  }


Future<void> _configureSdk() async {
  await Purchases.setLogLevel(LogLevel.debug);

  PurchasesConfiguration? configuration;

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    //
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    configuration = PurchasesConfiguration('apikey');
  }

  if (configuration != null) {
    await Purchases.configure(configuration);
    print('configure');
 await RevenueCatUI.presentPaywallIfNeeded('Premium');
  }
}



I tried it this way but the result is the same.

Have you setup the test products for local development as described in the revenuecat docs? As it does not fetch from the live store.

In the Subscriptions status code created by the app store connect , it says Missing Metadata, could it be caused by this?

if you are running locally it should not be hitting appstoreconnect yet, have a look at this for info: https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/test-and-launch/sandbox/apple-app-store#ios-14-only-testing-on-the-simulator

There were deficiencies made by the customer when setting up revenuecat and therefore the configuration could not be achieved. Working now
